# perl - what does this combination of 'keys' and 'map' do?

Tags: perl

I don't really have any experience with perl. I'm trying to understand this statement:

```
sub get_insert_query {
    my ( $self, $event ) = @_;
    my $table = $self->get_event_table();
    my $sql   = qq[ INSERT INTO $table SET ];
    my @pairs = map {qq[ `$_` = ? ]} keys %$event;
    $sql .= join( ',', @pairs );
    return ( $sql, values %$event );
}
```

`$self->get_event_table()`, in this case, returns the string "pbs". `$event` contains a bunch of arbitrary key-value pairs, I believe. I'm confused by

```
my @pairs = map {qq[ `$_` = ? ]} keys %$event;
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's analyze this expression:

```
map {qq[ `$_` = ? ]} keys %$event;
```

- `%$event` dereferences a hashref stored in `$event` variable
- `keys %$event` retrieves all the keys of this hash (as a list)
- `map { /*someexpr*/ } keys %$event` creates a new list based on the list returned by `keys` function. Each element of this new list is the one returned by /*someexpr*/. The latter is evaluated for each element of the old list, having this element in `$_`.

So now the only puzzling element is `` qq[ `$_` = ? ] `` expression. But that's quite simple to decypher too: `qq` is actually a double string quotation operator. Quoting the [**doc**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> While we usually think of quotes as literal values, in Perl they
>   function as operators, providing various kinds of interpolating and
>   pattern matching capabilities. Perl provides customary quote
>   characters for these behaviors, but also provides a way for you to
>   choose your quote character for any of them.

In this particular case, `[` and `]` symbols are used as delimiters. The result of this expression is basically the same as...

```
"`$_` = ?"
```

In short, this function takes a hashref where each element's key is a field name, and its value is, well, a value to insert into this field, and generates a prepared INSERT query (`$sql`) along with array of values to bind to this query (`values %$event`).

Comment: +1. `map` always scares me. However, your explanation is just awesome.

Comment: Just remember that `map` takes a list and returns another list. The thing inside the `map` determines how the input list is transformed.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
my @pairs = map {qq[ `$_` = ? ]} keys %$event;
```

is equivalent to:

```
my @pairs;
for my $tmp (keys %$event) {
    push @pairs, " `" . $tmp . "` = ? "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
my @pairs = map {qq[ `$_` = ? ]} keys %$event;

    $sql .= join( ',', @pairs );
```

generate the part of SQL prepared statement with keys as field names and question marks as values to be substituted.